# Norse mythology book by neil gaiman

Tags: norse

I want to have a collection of stories and myths about norse gods and their adventures i.e, the history of . I have searched google for long and couldn't find majority accepted book. I came to see about Neil Gaiman's book on norse mythology. Honestly i don't know anything about norse mythology other than asgard and thor stories. So i would like to get recommended for books

Comment: Are you asking how closely Gaiman's book keeps to the traditional mythology?

Comment: May be. I want to know whether Book of neil gaiman describes about all possible myths and adventures compared to other

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to read Gaiman's book, but the material from the Norse canon you will likely be most interested in is the [Prose Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda).

This work was written/compiled by written by the Icelandic scholar, lawspeaker and historian Snorri Sturluson around the year 1220, and is filled with important and often highly entertaining stories of the Norse gods.

You can find free translations online, such as this [PDF from Univerzeta Karlova](https://is.cuni.cz/studium/predmety/index.php?do=download&did=62028&kod=ARL100252).  My personal favorite English translation is [Kevin Crossley-Holland's The Norse Myths](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/497366.The_Norse_Myths), but there are numerous other translations in numerous languages.

Comment: Does it contain all possible stories and myth ?

Comment: @melvin "All possible stories and myths" is simply too broad. The Prose Edda is one of the original sources of these myths, but there will be other sources and traditions.

Comment: @melvin Not all, but surely the material you will be most interested in.  (In some sense, the modern novel has roots in the Icelandic sagas, and Snorri's text is highly readable, even today.  By contrast, the Poetic Edda doesn't have the same narrative appeal.  [Saxo Grammaticus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxo_Grammaticus) also wrote on these subjects in the [Gesta Danorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxo_Grammaticus#Gesta_Danorum), but more in the context of the history of Danish kings.)

Comment: Agreed. Gaiman's work is probably a good starting point if you want just the stories. There might be a few choices in interpretation, but unless you are doing academic work, it's not a big deal. Snorri's work should still be accessible to a layman, and contains most, but not quite all, known stories, but also quite a bit of other material. I'd suggest you check out the links given above.If you think itäs too much of a slog, try Gaiman's book instead.